# Kivy iOS toolchain build failing on macOS

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to build an app I've created in Kivy, however I need to build Kivy in the toolchain first which isn't working currently.
Here's my system information:

```
macOS = Sonoma 14.4
Xcode = 15.3
Cython = 0.29.36
python = 3.11
```

The Kivy documentation says to download Cython version `3.0.0`, however the Kivy-ios package requires the Cython version I currently have installed. Trying both doesn't work. I also switched from python version `3.12` to `3.11` which hasn't changed anything either.

## Note: Regardless of any changes made, the output shown below remains the exact same each time

The commmand `toolchain build kivy` outputs the logs shown below:

```
[DEBUG   ] ld: unknown options: -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/ffi -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/openssl -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.4.sdk
[DEBUG   ]
[DEBUG   ] The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
[DEBUG   ] _gdbm                _tkinter             ossaudiodev
[DEBUG   ] To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the modules name.
[DEBUG   ]
[DEBUG   ]
[DEBUG   ] The following modules found by detect_modules() in setup.py, have been
[DEBUG   ] built by the Makefile instead, as configured by the Setup files:
[DEBUG   ] _asyncio             _bisect              _blake2
[DEBUG   ] _bz2                 _codecs_cn           _codecs_hk
[DEBUG   ] _codecs_iso2022      _codecs_jp           _codecs_kr
[DEBUG   ] _codecs_tw           _contextvars         _crypt
[DEBUG   ] _csv                 _ctypes              _ctypes_test
[DEBUG   ] _datetime            _elementtree         _hashlib
[DEBUG   ] _heapq               _json                _lsprof
[DEBUG   ] _md5                 _multibytecodec      _opcode
[DEBUG   ] _pickle              _queue               _random
[DEBUG   ] _sha1                _sha256              _sha3
[DEBUG   ] _sha512              _socket              _sqlite3
[DEBUG   ] _ssl                 _struct              _testbuffer
[DEBUG   ] _testimportmultiple   _testinternalcapi    array
[DEBUG   ] audioop              binascii             cmath
[DEBUG   ] fcntl                grp                  math
[DEBUG   ] mmap                 pyexpat              resource
[DEBUG   ] select               syslog               termios
[DEBUG   ] unicodedata          zlib
[DEBUG   ]
[DEBUG   ]
[DEBUG   ] Failed to build these modules:
[DEBUG   ] _curses              _curses_panel        _dbm
[DEBUG   ] _decimal             _lzma                _multiprocessing
[DEBUG   ] _posixshmem          _posixsubprocess     _statistics
[DEBUG   ] _testcapi            _testclinic          _testmultiphase
[DEBUG   ] _typing              _uuid                _xxsubinterpreters
[DEBUG   ] _xxtestfuzz          _zoneinfo            nis
[DEBUG   ] readline             spwd                 xxlimited
[DEBUG   ] xxlimited_35
[DEBUG   ]
[DEBUG   ] running build_scripts
[DEBUG   ] creating build/scripts-3.11
[DEBUG   ] copying and adjusting /Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/build/python3/iphoneos-arm64/Python-3.11.6/Tools/scripts/pydoc3 -> build/scripts-3.11
[DEBUG   ] copying and adjusting /Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/build/python3/iphoneos-arm64/Python-3.11.6/Tools/scripts/idle3 -> build/scripts-3.11
[DEBUG   ] copying and adjusting /Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/build/python3/iphoneos-arm64/Python-3.11.6/Tools/scripts/2to3 -> build/scripts-3.11
[DEBUG   ] changing mode of build/scripts-3.11/pydoc3 from 644 to 755
[DEBUG   ] changing mode of build/scripts-3.11/idle3 from 644 to 755
[DEBUG   ] changing mode of build/scripts-3.11/2to3 from 644 to 755
[DEBUG   ] renaming build/scripts-3.11/pydoc3 to build/scripts-3.11/pydoc3.11
[DEBUG   ] renaming build/scripts-3.11/idle3 to build/scripts-3.11/idle3.11
[DEBUG   ] renaming build/scripts-3.11/2to3 to build/scripts-3.11/2to3-3.11
Exception in thread background thread for pid 42357:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 1639, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 2641, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 2332, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 826, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2:

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j10 'CFLAGS=-O3 -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/ffi -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/openssl -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.4.sdk'

  STDOUT:
Makefile:2823: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlparse.o'
Makefile:1031: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlparse.o'
Makefile:2824: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlrole.o'
Makefile:1034: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlrole.o'
Makefile:2825: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmltok.o'
Makefile:1037: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmltok.o'
/tmp/tmpzm3k119s -c -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -O3 -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/ffi -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/openssl -I/Users/... (356726 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/toolchain", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1670, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1407, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1483, in build
    build_recipes(args.recipe, ctx)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1231, in build_recipes
    recipe.execute()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 758, in execute
    self.build_all()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 78, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 858, in build_all
    self.build(plat)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 78, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 844, in build
    self.build_platform(plat)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/recipes/python3/__init__.py", line 117, in build_platform
    shprint(sh.make, self.ctx.concurrent_make, "CFLAGS={}".format(build_env["CFLAGS"]))
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 60, in shprint
    for line in cmd:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 882, in __next__
    self.wait()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 799, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sh.py", line 826, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2:

  RAN: /usr/bin/make -j10 'CFLAGS=-O3 -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/ffi -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/openssl -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.4.sdk'

  STDOUT:
Makefile:2823: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlparse.o'
Makefile:1031: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlparse.o'
Makefile:2824: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlrole.o'
Makefile:1034: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmlrole.o'
Makefile:2825: warning: overriding commands for target `Modules/expat/xmltok.o'
Makefile:1037: warning: ignoring old commands for target `Modules/expat/xmltok.o'
/tmp/tmpzm3k119s -c -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -O3 -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/ffi -I/Users/jack/Desktop/KivyBuilds/dist/include/iphoneos-arm64/openssl -I/Users/... (356726 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:

(venv_grooveID) jack@jacks-mbp KivyBuilds %
```

The output for the command `toolchain status`:

```
audiostream  - Not built
click        - Not built
curly        - Not built
cymunk       - Not built
ffmpeg       - Not built
ffpyplayer   - Not built
flask        - Not built
freetype     - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:50:38.753344)
hostopenssl  - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:51:24.359019)
hostpython3  - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 23:01:44.053676)
ios          - Not built
itsdangerous - Not built
jinja2       - Not built
kivent_core  - Not built
kivy         - Not built
kiwisolver   - Not built
libcurl      - Not built
libffi       - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:54:32.531345)
libjpeg      - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:55:13.519545)
libpng       - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:56:02.149758)
libzbar      - Not built
markupsafe   - Not built
materialyoucolor - Not built
matplotlib   - Not built
netifaces    - Not built
numpy        - Not built
openssl      - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:57:24.156832)
photolibrary - Not built
pillow       - Not built
plyer        - Not built
py3dns       - Not built
pycrypto     - Not built
pykka        - Not built
pyobjus      - Not built
python3      - Not built
pyyaml       - Not built
sdl2         - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 22:58:10.556457)
sdl2_image   - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 23:02:03.743875)
sdl2_mixer   - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 23:02:23.058399)
sdl2_ttf     - Build OK (built at 2024-03-20 23:03:12.483293)
werkzeug     - Not built
zbarlight    - Not built
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you